# Tomcat 5.0.28 OutOfMemoryError

Tags: tomcat, jvm

I'm running a Tomcat service and kept on getting outofmemoryerror.

I have tried increasing the heap size using 2 different methods and both failed:

```
"%EXECUTABLE%" //US//%SERVICE_NAME% ++JvmOptions "-Djava.io.tmpdir=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp;-Xmx1024m;-Xms128m" 

"%EXECUTABLE%" //US//%SERVICE_NAME% ++JvmOptions "-Djava.io.tmpdir=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp" --JvmMx 1024m --JvmMs 128m"
```

Still getting the same outofmemoryerror.

This is on a server and we have sufficient memory.

Comment: What is happening when the error occurs? Is there a specific page that is causing the issue?

Comment: Tomcat 5.0 is prehistoric. You'd be well advised to move to something more recent, for purposes of better documentation if nothing else.

Comment: Run a profiler to nail down the memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How often is this happening?   I inherited a large web application that runs on Tomcat 5 on Windows Server 2003.   It runs out of memory about every 28 days.    Given the antiquated, undocumented nature of the code base, I just added a scheduled task to restart it once a week.

Comment: It's happening everyday now. We tried different configuation - restarting the Tomcat instance .. yet failed